# Why does only one character get electrocuted in this scene in Wonder Woman 1984?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, wonder-woman-1984

In the movie, towards the end

> We see Wonder Woman defeat Cheetah as they are fighting in the water and the power line falls into the water and eletrocutes Cheetah thereby fainting.

Why doesn't Wonder Woman get electrocuted as well ?

Comment: Doesn't the first movie say she is the daughter of Zeus, god of Thunder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the one hand, we have Diana, a.k.a Wonder Woman, daughter of the Greco-Roman deity who was known for smiting mortals with lightning. When Ares, the God of War, tried to electrocute her in the previous film, she took his own lightning and redirected it at him. When severely weakened, she can shove a 60 ton tank to the side at a good 30 miles per hour; at her peak power at that time, she can jump several thousand feet in the air, when she is not actually flying. She appears to be able to more or less swing on a lightning bolt with her lasso, and does not appear to be concerned about being hit.

On the other hand, we have Barbara "Cheetah" Minerva, a human being altered by the Dreamstone to have increased strength, speed, and viciousness. Her baseline power allowed her to throw an adult man of average-looking mass some twenty or thirty feet. At the height of her enhancement, she can severely damage Diana's armor when allowed to claw at it essentially unopposed, and jump perhaps a few hundred feet in the air, maximum.

Which one of these characters would be most bothered by a serious electric shock?

Comment: If Cheetah asked for being like Diana, shouldn't all those powers of Wonder Woman be mirrored?

Comment: All magic has limitations. It's one thing to mind-control people or rebuild a wall, but we saw that making more nuclear weapons was a greater exertion for Maxwell Lord. I think we can assume that for an artifact created by one god, making someone as powerful as a god (i.e. Wonder Woman) might be a little too much for its intrinsic powers. Now, could Maxwell Lord have made Cheetah as strong as Wonder Woman, at least in terms of physical strength, by taking enough strength from people making wishes? I am going to say yes, because he had enough strength to hold her back at the end.

Comment: But he was not about to give her all that power and not keep it to defend himself.

Answer (score 1):

> They were both fully submerged in the water, and Diana had nothing to insulate her (especially her exposed face and hands) from the electrical current, which would suggest she was subjected to the same level of voltage that Barbara was. Apparently, she was just more *resistant* to it. I didn't see anything in the film to indicate that there was anything more to it than that.